# Ranking on Multiple Columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table visual based on the Contoso database. It looks like this:

[image]

Year of Sale and Product Category are fields in the fact table. The Sales Amount is coming from a measure. The sales rank is being calculated as follows:

```
Sales Rank = 
    RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED('Online Sales'),
        CALCULATE(
            [Sales Amount], 
            ALLEXCEPT('Online Sales', 'Online Sales'[Year of Sale], 'Online Sales'[Product Category])
            ),,,
            DENSE
        )
```

This is close but what I actually want is the rank by year of sale and category. For example, for 2007, the category of Cameras and camcorders should have a sales rank of 1 and Home Appliances should be 2. For 2008, Home Appliances should be 1 and Computers should be 2 etc. I think my measure is close but it's not exactly there and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sales Rank =
    RANKX (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Online Sales'[Product Category] ),
        'Online Sales'[Sales Amount],
        ,
        ,
        DENSE
    )
```